# WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion in /home/user/MyApp/AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-ndk

I'm using the Android ndk-r8e, and I'm having a problem building a project. I get the above-mentioned error message. I've checked my AndroidManifest.xml and minSdkVersion is set to 15, which is what I intend. According to the error message, APP_PLATFORM is set to android-14, which is smaller, not larger than minSdkVersion, so why am I getting the error?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making them the same?

Comment: I've tried setting minSdkVersion to 14 but I get the same error.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 24):

Check your `jni/Application.mk`

You should have following line:-

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

If you do not have that line then version of your SDK is taken from `project.properties` files.

Comment: My project does not have a jni/Application.mk file. In project.properties, target is set to android-15.

Comment: My project only has jni/Android.mk. In project.properties, target is set to android-15.
I have tried to create a new jni/Application.mk with APP_PLATFORM := android-14 as its only line, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You should create `jni/Application.mk` It is fine to have 1 line `APP_PLATFORM := android-14` Second line might be `APP_ABI := all`. Do clean `ndk-build clean` and if message has not gone try to build 'HelloJNI` from `$NDK/samples`

Comment: @Max What about the other way?  My "AndroidManifest.xml" has no "minSdkVersion" in it, and only recently the NDK-BUILD started complaining.  My Application.mk in teh JNI is set for APP_PLATFORM := android-19...   My build.gradle has the minSdkVersion set to 19.  I even tried to add the minSdkVersion to the Manifest XML, but no change.  It did NOT spit out warnings few months ago. This moving target environment really sucks.