# NDK Build error...on doing ndk-build

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I m getting following error. Help me resolve this

> C:/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/cpu-features.h:52:6: error: #error Unknown or unsupported ARM architecture
>   make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/jpeg/jidctfst.o] Error 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NDK: WARNING: APP\_PLATFORM android-9 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872254/android-ndk-warning-app-platform-android-9-is-larger-than-androidminsdkversio).

Comment: please give more information on your configuration (Android.mk and Application.mk files), what are you trying to compile and how ?